# Windows batch command to move all folders in a directory with exceptions

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, move

I am trying to write a Windows Batch file that will allow me to move all directories within a given source directory into a target directory that exists within that source directory.

Obviously my move command with need to only apply to directories and also exclude the target directory from being processed.

Is this possible with a Windows batch command?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) (present in recent versions of windows or downloadable from the [WRK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17657)) can do this, just use the `/xd` switch to exclude the target directory from the copy;

```
robocopy c:\source\ c:\source\target\ *.* /E /XD c:\source\target\ /move
```

Comment: What about multiple exceptions or multiple directories to skip in moving ? Improve your answer by adding that too.

Answer (score 7):

```
FOR /d %%i IN (*) DO IF NOT "%%i"=="target" move "%%i" target
```

Answer (score 1):

That won't work - you'll get an error telling you the target directory is inside the source directory or so, even if you explicitly exclude the target directory. What you can do is move the directories to a temporary location which is not under the source, and then move them into the target.

BTW, using the `move` command won't let you specify folders to exclude. For that you can use `xcopy`, but note that it will *copy* the folders, as opposed to *move* them. If that matters, you can delete whatever you want afterwards, just make sure you don't delete the target dir, which is in the source dir...

Answer (score 1):

Using robocopy included with Windows 7, I found the /XD option did not prevent the source folder from also being moved.

**Solution:**

```
SET MoveDirSource=\\Server\Folder
SET MoveDirDestination=Z:\Folder
FOR /D %%i IN ("%MoveDirSource%\*") DO ROBOCOPY /MOVE /E "%%i" "%MoveDirDestination%\%%~nxi"
```

This loops through the top level folders and runs robocopy for each.

Answer (score 1):

NB: Robocopy mentioned above using the /move flag will copy the files and then delete them from the source folder rather than *moving* the files.  This may be critical if moving large numbers of files from one location to another on the same disk (because move is virtually instantaneous, while copying is a much slower operation)

Answer (score 1):

On windows batch:

```
FOR /d %%i IN (MySourceDirectory\*) DO move "%%i" MyTargetDirectory\%%~ni
```

The above command moves all directories found in MySourceDirectory (/d) to MyTargetDirectory using the original directory name 
(~ni) Robocopy's move first does a copy, then delete, so it is slower.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
move c:\fromDir\*.* c:\toDir\
```

Comment: at least on winserver2012r2, this does work only for moving files, but not subdirectories - and does not cover any option for 'exceptions'