# Move directories with wildcards into another directory with robocopy or move in cmd

Tags: windows, move, robocopy

I read [Windows batch command to move all folders in a directory with exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461373/windows-batch-command-to-move-all-folders-in-a-directory-with-exceptions) but this did not work with wildcards. I want to move all folders (!), not files, inside a folder into 2010.

I have 2010-01, 2010-02, 2010-03, ... but also 2011-01, ...

How can I move (!) all folders including files inside 2010. For files this works perfectly with

`move *2010* 2010`

where the second 2010 is the destination folder.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `robocopy` is the right tool for you. You can use the following command to move all directories *and* files from the directory **source_dir** into **target_dir**, preserving the directory structure:

```
c:\robocopy source_dir target_dir /S /MOVE
```

Comment: FEHLER: Ungültiger Parameter #1: C:\Users\Michael\Pictures\2002\*2004*. Does not seem to support wildcards.

Comment: @MichaelS., _robocopy_ is a tool to manage directories and operates on all files/directories by default, you can exclude files and directories, though; the following example does not operate over _*.doc_ files `/XF *doc`, and this does not operate on directories that finish with _old_ `/XD *old`.