# How to move all files excecpt one from parent folder into a new child folder using windows command?

Tags: windows, command-line

How to move all files except one from the parent folder into a new child folder using the windows command?

I need to move all files except one file named index.html from the parent folder into a new child folder.

I have tried the below command but it is not working.

> move parent_folder ./parent_folder/child_folder

Please refer below

**Current Folder Structure**

[image]

Required Folder Structure

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved the above requirement using '**robocopy**' command.

**Command**

```
robocopy parent_folder parent_folder/child_folder/ *.* /E /XD child_folder /XF index.html /move
```

**Referred URL** - [Windows batch command to move all folders in a directory with exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461373/windows-batch-command-to-move-all-folders-in-a-directory-with-exceptions)

**Screenshot #1**

[image]

**Screenshot #2**

[image]